# Wordpress only show posts from specific author role

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I want to include a filter into the loop, so only the posts from authors with a certain user role appear. I want to show them in a certain category e.g "verified authors", so i need to check if this is the right category in the loop aswell.

This is what I have got:

functions.php

```
function get_author_role()
{
global $authordata;

$author_roles = $authordata->roles;
$author_role = array_shift($author_roles);

return $author_role;
 }
```

loop in category template

```
<?php
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
//how to check if author = specific role and check if category 'verifiedauthors" ?
endwhile;endif;
?>
```

Comment: sorry I mean a created user role

Answer (score 0):

You can add author query to your loop.

```
// Example
$atuhors_array = array( 1,4,5,3 );
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'author__in' => $authors_array ) );
```

Once you must create array and Add're looking for authors this array.

```
$blogusers = get_users( 'blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=subscriber' );
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
     $authors_array[]= $user->ID;
```

After your adding authors to array, now you can use author query.

Comment: does that mean, I have to add all authors manually to the array to add them to 'verified'? I just want to get all posts from a certain userrole.. so just show posts from e.g subcribers

Comment: so the 1,2,3,4 represent categories?